# Provide feedback during suitescript restlet processing?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a NetSuite RESTlet that is doing some searching and processing and then displaying the results in a portlet. All is well there. However, if the process takes a while, I would like to provide feedback to the client that something is actually happening. What would be the best method of doing so? I could break up the search into batches and provide feedback between calls but that leads to extra governance I don't need.

Here's my searching code. (Boilerplate). I thought about calling the RESTlet again and then providing a callback with the record count, but I am required to send auth params. Why is that?

What is the best way to go about this?

```
function doWork() {
    // do the search
    var accountSearch = search.create({
        type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
        columns: searchColumns,
        filters: searchFilters
    });
    // GOVERNANCE: 5 
    var searchResultsPagedData = accountSearch.runPaged({
        'pageSize': 1000
    });

    if (searchResultsPagedData && searchResultsPagedData.count > 0) {
        var foundIDs = [];
        for (var pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < searchResultsPagedData.pageRanges.length; pageIndex++) {
            var pageRange = searchResultsPagedData.pageRanges[pageIndex];
            if (pageRange.index >= max)
                break;

            var searchPage = searchResultsPagedData.fetch({ index: pageRange.index });

            // THIS IS WHAT I HAD IN MIND
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ "recordType": "resultCallback", "index": pageRange.index });
            var restletUrl = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId: 'customscript_script_id',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_deploy_id',
            });


            var response = https.post({
                url: restletUrl,
                body: jsonText
            });
            log.debug({
                title: 'response',
                details: response
            })


            // Iterate over the list of results on the current page
            searchPage.data.forEach(function (result) {
                // Process the individual result
                var internalid = result.id;
                // etc etc
            });
        };
    }
    var returnJson = {
        'accountslength': records.length,
        'contactlength': contactRecords.length,
        'accounts': records,
        'contacts': contactRecords
    };

    return returnJson;
}
```

Response give me;

```
"type":"http.ClientResponse","code":401
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally do this sort of thing in two parts.

First I return the target set to the client. That lets you know how big the load is.

Then send each target record to the suitelet or restlet one at a time. 
You can advance a progress notice as each target is processed and you reduce the chance of running into governance issues

Comment: I think this is going to be the way it will need to be handled, although I'd do it in batches vs one record at a time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Suitelet for the feedback to the user?

Comment: If I use a Suitelet I am getting 'http.ClientResponse","code":206' and `You are not allowed to navigate directly to this page.`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom record with a counter that gets updated after every record update, something like (10 out of 100 records processed) and have the portlet check on it every x seconds.

Comment: How would that behave with multiple users accessing the portlet/restlet?

Comment: If multiple users can use the Restlet and you want them to see their own progress you would need to store the userid along with the custom record. One thing though I forgot to mention is that you might want to check if you run into any timeout/governance issues as normally Restlets are not meant to be used for massive updates.